# pandoc can't process \MakeUppercase

Tags: pandoc

I try convert latex book to OpenOffice ODT format.
And my pandoc 1.17.2 (Debian 9x64) can't process \MakeUppercase macros.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\begin{document}
test \MakeUppercase{Case Text.} test
\end{document}
```

running pandoc, I get: (plain format here - for clearness)

```
$ pandoc -f latex -t plain  main-uppercase.tex
test test
```

Now I found doubtful way: from script rewrite preamble and write:

```
\renewcommand{\MakeUppercase}[1]{<upp_start>#1<upp_stop>}
```

and process odt-file (pandoc convert correctly  with this "tags") automatically via ooobasic macros from LibreOffice, but...
May be there is another way?
Thank you.

ps: **\textsc{}** - work correctly

Comment: I think https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues is better place to report this. I made quick search there and found no indication the issue had been raised. There is also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your Pandoc.

I'm on v2.7.1.

The `input.tex`:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\begin{document}
test \MakeUppercase{Case Text.} test
\end{document}
```

The command:

```
pandoc -f latex -t plain input.tex
```

The output:

```
test CASE TEXT. test
```